# Powershell script that lists where class property is used

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2013, resharper, envdte

I am trying to write a script that can provide me with a list of all classes/methods that (in my Visual Studio 2013 C# solution) use a specified class property - with similar output as ReSharpers "Find Usages" command, but then run as a PS script or from the command-line.

I have looked at the APIs for ReSharper and EnvDTE, but have not been able to figure out how to do this. Does anybody have any ideas or starting points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The keyword here is Roslyn, [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ) you can find the "How do I go from an ISolution to Find All References on a symbol/type?" topic.

I think the most convenient way is to code it in C# and then wrap it to a genuine C# cmdlet.